# BOM Query with Hierarchyid

Tags: sql

I have try 2 method for query the BOM first using materialized path and hierarchyid. But the result is still incorrect. The result for ItemNumber /1/5/ with qty 3 is 38.12, This result must 114.36 because multiply by qty. Could some one explain me how to solve this problem.

Here's the code :

```
declare @BOMStructure as table  
(
PartNumber varchar(14)not null ,
Descript varchar(50)not null,
Qty integer not null default 0,
Price Decimal (10,2) default 0,
ItemNumber hierarchyid not null primary key 
)

INSERT @BOMStructure 
(PartNumber ,Descript ,Qty ,Price ,ItemNumber)
VALUES  ('13400201001','MAIN ASSEMBLY',1,0,'/'),
        ('00150060060005','BASIC TANK',1,0,'/1/'),
        ('11012142200503','SHELL',1,789.89,'/1/1/'),
        ('12052140503','TOP CONE',1,226.75,'/1/2/'),
        ('13052140503','BOTTOM CONE',1,226.75,'/1/3/'),
        ('140104116508','PIPE LEG',3,39.75,'/1/4/'),
        ('15004104','BALL FEET',3,0,'/1/5/'),
        ('1510413504','SLEEVE',1,18.03,'/1/5/1/'),
        ('1524809510','ADJUSTABLE BOLT',1,12.82,'/1/5/2/'),
        ('1530411604','BASE',1,7.27,'/1/5/3/')

-- GetAncestor
-- Mengupdate 
select  PartNumber, Descript,Qty,Price, (select sum (Price * Qty)
                                        from @BOMStructure where ItemNumber .IsDescendantOf (p.ItemNumber ) = 1 ) as [TotalPrice], 
        ItemNumber .ToString() as [Hierarcy], ItemNumber .GetLevel() as [Level]

from @BOMStructure as P;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by multiplying by `p.qty`:

```
SELECT partnumber, descript, qty, price, 
       p.qty * (SELECT Sum(price * qty) 
                FROM bomstructure 
                WHERE itemnumber.Isdescendantof(p.itemnumber) = 1
               ) as [TotalPrice], 
       itemnumber.Tostring() as [Hierarcy], 
       itemnumber.Getlevel() as [Level] 
FROM bomstructure as P;
```

However, I'm not 100% sure that this does what you need for all the rows.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28bc8/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For ItemNumber /1/5/ is correct. But for ItemNumber /1/ and / still incorrect. Please guide me to solve this problem.
<blink>
13400201001 MAIN ASSEMBLY 1 0.00 1400.76 / 0
00150060060005 BASIC TANK 1 0.00 1400.76 /1/ 1
</blink>

Comment: @Hawk . . . Please do not do me any "favors" by reformatting my queries.  I format queries in my answers pretty much exactly the way that I want them to be written.  I am very particular about my formatting and do not want it changed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for notifying me. Although I do not see them *favors*, I will consider your request duly.